# padding left and right (px) in tailwindcss not working

Tags: padding

i have a **div** wherein i put my **p** tag. i want the p to be in center so i used px-auto and also px-8 something like that but the px is not workint at all, i tried py and its working fine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4pqY.png)
below is my code.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blqLA.png)

tried py and its working completly fine.

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)